# Running x86-64 ASM on a x86-32 processor

Tags: assembly, virtual-machine, emulation, x86-64

I'm taking an assembly language course and it's taught targeting x86-64 platforms. My laptop is pretty antiquated and still running a 32 bit x86 processor, specifically an Intel Core Duo T2500. Is there a way to run a virtual machine that supports 64bit addressing on my machine?

Comment: AMD used to provide an x64 emulator before the chip was released. I forget what it was called.

Comment: vmware doesn't relate here since it's not an emulator, it cannot run x86_64 instructions in 32-bit mode

Comment: vmware is a hypervisor, which is different from emulator http://stackoverflow.com/a/6234760/995714

Comment: if some answer helps you then you should [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 3):

[QEMU](http://qemu.org/) should be able to emulate x86_64: [Features](http://qemu.weilnetz.de/qemu-doc.html#intro_005ffeatures)

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try to use QEMU and a mini Linux LiveCD image (like Knoppix, Puppy, or DSL).

Answer (score 1):

[Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) is another x86_64 emulator. But you should think of using an emulator since everything is emulated and it's too slow to run a full operating system. Unless you use some assembler that has it's own OS or don't require an OS to run, otherwise you'll waste time waiting for the OS to boot and then run your assembler.

IMHO I think it's better off buying a new laptop. You can buy new Chrome books within 200USD although I don't remember if there are any x86 Chrome books that price, or buy old laptops with only 100USD (more or less)

Comment: Speed isn't that much of a concern for doing homework. I with I had 100USD to spare, but I'm on a tight student budget.

Comment: In that case there's no other solution then. If possible, sold the old laptop and buy a new old one with a few more bucks. If not, you could try [Menuet OS](http://www.menuetos.net/index.htm) in an emulator. It's a super lite 32/64 bit OS written in assembly that fits in a floppy drive and you can also use it to write programs. I've tried bochs and qemu to boot a live 64-bit Linux CD on my old laptop and then after a long time waiting I surrendered

Comment: It's all good. I am just going to boot a Linux live CD on our computers in the CS lab. I just wanted a solution to do my work at home. I can't afford to buy a computer, and I don't think I'd get very much for my 2007 laptop.